# How can i get the Session Settings and Session Timeout from Salesforce using Rest call?

Tags: rest-api, api, soap

Is there a Rest API call I can make to get the Session Timeout Value under Session Settings in Salesforce?

If I retrieve back the UserInfo in the JSON there are URL's:

```json
"urls": {
    "enterprise": 
    "metadata":
    "partner": 
    "rest":
    "sobjects": 
    "search": 
    "query": 
    "recent":
    "tooling_soap": 
    "tooling_rest": 
    "profile": 
    "feeds":
    "groups": 
    "users": 
    "feed_items": 
    "feed_elements": 
    "custom_domain": 
},
```

All of the above have a URL associated. Can I use any of them to make a call and get the session timeout value ?

Comment: Have you checked the [`SecuritySettings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm#SecuritySettingsSessionSettings) documentaiton for SessionSettings?

Comment: that doesnt really tell me how i can make a call using REST to get the session timeout value in a json response. Is there a SOQL select i can do if that is easier .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Tooling API which is returned in `tooling_rest` in your response in your question. It has a [query resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm) where you can get `sessionTimeout` or other fields from [SessionSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm#SecuritySettingsSessionSettings)

`/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,sessionTimeout+FROM+SessionSettings`

In the response, you'll see:

```json
{
  "size" : 1,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "SessionSettings",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "SessionSettings",
      "url" : "/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/SessionSettings/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "Id" : "000000000000000AAA",
    "SessionTimeout" : "TwoHours"
  } ]
}
```

In terms of knowing when the Tooling API supports an object - the easiest way is to just call GET on

`/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects`

Which will then return the information about the objects available

```json
...
{
    "activateable" : false,
    "associateEntityType" : null,
    "associateParentEntity" : null,
    "createable" : true,
    "custom" : false,
    "customSetting" : false,
    "deepCloneable" : false,
    "deletable" : true,
    "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
    "feedEnabled" : false,
    "hasSubtypes" : false,
    "isInterface" : false,
    "isSubtype" : false,
    "keyPrefix" : "0HE",
    "label" : "Entity",
    "labelPlural" : "Entity",
    "layoutable" : false,
    "mergeable" : false,
    "mruEnabled" : false,
    "name" : "SessionSettings",
    "queryable" : true,
    "replicateable" : false,
    "retrieveable" : true,
    "searchable" : false,
    "triggerable" : false,
    "undeletable" : false,
    "updateable" : true,
    "urls" : {
      "rowTemplate" : "/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/SessionSettings/{ID}",
      "describe" : "/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/SessionSettings/describe",
      "sobject" : "/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/SessionSettings"
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Perfect,thanks.  I just wonder why Salesforce returns an enumeration of type string for sessiontimeout instead of an actual number in minutes or so. If they add a new enum value , then need to change all my apps to counter for it